# Printing in table format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

For example I have a 2D python list called matrix, and the rows of the marix is given below

```
['Adam', 57.6271186440678, 2.542372881355932, 0.0, 39.83050847457627]
['BAMON', 40.90909090909091, 9.090909090909092, 0.0, 50.0]
['BANESH', 72.61146496815287, 0.6369426751592356, 0.0, 26.751592356687897]
['BASA', 60.317460317460316, 4.761904761904762, 1.5873015873015872, 33.333333333333336]
```

I want to print the 2D matrix as table with Header(Name, High Income, Medium Income in Asia, Low Income, Extreme Income in America ) and 2 digits after decimal will be considered.

| Name | High Income | Medium Income in Asia | Low Income | Extreme Income in America |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 57.62 | 2.54 | 0.0 | 39.83 |
| Bamon | 40.90 | 9.09 | 0.0 | 50.0 |

How can I print it as a table or table like structure in python.

Comment: How do you expect the result to look? What is a "beautiful" "table or table like structure" to you? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear info. I added a sample table

Comment: Not as a markdown table - as the actual format that Python should output.

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = [
    ['Adam', 57.6271186440678, 2.542372881355932, 0.0, 39.83050847457627],
    ['BAMON', 40.90909090909091, 9.090909090909092, 0.0, 50.0],
    ['BANESH', 72.61146496815287, 0.6369426751592356, 0.0, 26.751592356687897],
    ['BASA', 60.317460317460316, 4.761904761904762, 1.5873015873015872, 33.333333333333336],
]
col_names = ['High Income', 'Medium Income in Asia', 'Low Income', 'Extreme 
Income in America']

matrix.insert(0, col_names)

for e in matrix:
    if e == matrix[0]:
        print(f'{e[0]}\t\t{e[1]}\t\t{e[2]}\t\t{e[3]}')
    else:
        print(f'{e[0]}\t\t\t{round(e[1], 2)}\t\t\t\t\t\t{round(e[2], 
        2)}\t\t\t{round(e[3], 2)}')
```

I think there is a better way to format the tabs in the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the situation using this package
https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
table = PrettyTable()

table.field_names = ["Name", "Low Deviation in America", "Medium Income Percentage", "High Deviation in America", "Extreme Income"]
for row in matrix:
  if(len(row)>0):
    x.add_row(row)
print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

(Adjusted from https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/data-in-table-format-python/)

```
d = [['Adam', 57.6271186440678, 2.542372881355932, 0.0, 39.83050847457627],
['BAMON', 40.90909090909091, 9.090909090909092, 0.0, 50.0], 
['BANESH', 72.61146496815287, 0.6369426751592356, 0.0, 26.751592356687897],
['BASA', 60.317460317460316, 4.761904761904762, 1.5873015873015872, 33.333333333333336]]
     
print ("{:<8} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} ".format('Name', 'High Income', 'Medium Income in Asia', 'Low Income', 'Extreme Income in America'))

for v in d:
    name, high_income, medium_income, low_income, extreme_income = v
    print ("{:<8} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15} {:<15}".format( name, high_income, medium_income, low_income, extreme_income))
```

You can specify the column widths by adjusting the numbers inside the curly braces.

Hope this helps.